# Calculating sales tax with Stripe tax

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm trying to calculate Stripe tax using Stripe Python library

```
resp = stripe.tax.Calculation.create(
    currency=USD_ISO_CODE,
    line_items=[{"amount": total_base_cost, "reference": "L1"}],
    shipping_cost={"amount": shipping_cost, "tax_code": "txcd_92010001"},
    customer_details={
        "address": {
            "line1": "500 Anton Blvd",
            "city": "Costa Mesa",
            "state": "CA",
            "postal_code": "92626",
            "country": "US",
        },
        "address_source": "billing",
    },
)
```

I've printed the response from Stripe here

```
{
  "amount_total": 1354611,
  "currency": "usd",
  "customer": null,
  "customer_details": {
    "address": {
      "city": "Costa Mesa",
      "country": "US",
      "line1": "500 Anton Blvd",
      "line2": null,
      "postal_code": "92626",
      "state": "CA"
    },
    "address_source": "billing",
    "ip_address": null,
    "tax_ids": [],
    "taxability_override": "none"
  },
  "expires_at": 1695435437,
  "id": "taxcalc_1NscS9GRnWL3YYIB9Tn5yAAG",
  "livemode": false,
  "object": "tax.calculation",
  "shipping_cost": {
    "amount": 0,
    "amount_tax": 0,
    "tax_behavior": "exclusive",
    "tax_code": "txcd_92010001"
  },
  "tax_amount_exclusive": 0,
  "tax_amount_inclusive": 0,
  "tax_breakdown": [
    {
      "amount": 0,
      "inclusive": false,
      "tax_rate_details": {
        "country": "HK",
        "percentage_decimal": "0.0",
        "state": null,
        "tax_type": null
      },
      "taxability_reason": "not_subject_to_tax",
      "taxable_amount": 0
    }
  ],
  "tax_date": 1695262637
}
```

Afaik California has destination-based sales tax of 7.25% and this is not being calculated. The reason given in the response is `"taxability_reason": "not_subject_to_tax"`.

In my Stripe tax settings, I've set the goods to `Tangible goods` and the business origin is HK.

What am I doing wrong here? Why is Stripe not adding in CA's sales tax?

Comment: Sales from out of country are not subject to California sales tax if shipped directly to the purchaser.  https://www.cdtfa.ca.gov/lawguides/vol1/sutr/sales-and-use-tax-regulations-art11-all.html#:~:text=Sales%20tax%20does%20not%20apply%20when%20the%20property%20is%20sold,retailer%20to%20the%20foreign%20country.